# Unable to sucessfuly post from client to WCF WSDL service

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl, client

I have created a WSDL service with WCF with 3 service contracts-methods, I´m able to test it with soap application and all 3 service methods work as expected.
I´m trying to post data to the Getcallback service contract, from soap application the method works, but while trying to test with postman it did error with HTTP  415 
From what I have found on possible causes this can be because the server is not expecting to receive the data, but from all, I have read I feel is correct.

I need to retrieve a string value from the client, this is why I´m using JS to post to the server method expecting a string value.

[Service contracts [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7uEw.png)
Sample JS call to soap service

[Sample post-call from client to server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePyLk.png)

I have also tried to make the call with pure js, but the same issue.
I appreciate anyone helps on this matter

[Error from client call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jESWh.png)

[Postman error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr3rA.png)

Comment: Please provide your source code so that people can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

This was fix by adding SOAPAction and Content-Type to request.